# R function ifelse returning only evaluation of the last row

Tags: r

I have a 200 x 10 matrix of digits , either 2 or 7 called predictions.

I'm trying to return the majority for each row using this code.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(predictions)) {
  if_else(mean(predictions[i,] == 7) > 0.5, 7, 2)
}
```

This returns nothing at all on the console.

If I try to assign a variable to it like so:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(predictions)) {
  if_else(mean(predictions[i,] == 7) > 0.5, 7, 2)
} -> ens
```

it returns the result for the last row.

If I try to assign a variable to it at the beginning, the variable contains NULL:

```
ens <- for(i in 1:nrow(predictions)) {
  if_else(mean(predictions[i,] == 7) > 0.5, 7, 2)
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Your previous code is not returning anything because you're not saving the results of each iteration. To return the majority for each row, the *minimum* number of modifications to achieve what you want should be like this:

```
majority <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(predictions)){
  majority[i] <- if_else(mean(predictions[i,]==7)>0.5,7,2) 
}
```

Then, depending on what you wanted to do with the vector of majorities, you could either mutate a row number or bind it to the original predictions matrix.

**EDIT**

If you want to step away from using for loops, you can use apply statements. If you want to stay in the tidyverse (I see you're using `dplyr::if_else()`), check out the `purrr` family of `map()` functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to be using `apply` here in row mode:

```r
ens <- apply(predictions, 1, function(x) {
    if (mean(x == 7) > 0.5) 7 else 2
})
```

Note that I am using regular `if ... else` non vectorized flow logic, since we are dealing with scalar aggregates of each row in the anonymous function being passed to `apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

You generally do not want or need to process data frame content with `for` loops.  You can generate the row means as a vector with the `rowMeans` function.  Try:

```
result <- ifelse(rowMeans(predictions) > 0.5, 7, 2)
```